# Styling HEAD elements to use them as datastore

Tags: javascript, css

An app comes with different GUI themes by providing a CSS file for each style. 
JavaScript needs to know the primary and secondary color of the current theme. 
These information are **only** stored inside the CSS file itself. 
The goal is to get these color information from CSS to JavaScript.

I had the idea to style the *invisible* DOM elements inside the `HEAD` (e.g. the `link` element itself), and then retrieve their color and background using JavaScript.

Would this idea work?

Comment: I wouldn't use the link element itself because it's not very extensible (you might want a whole palette of colours) but yes, using a set of hidden elements either in the head or body would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could make a hidden styled element and then use `display: none;` css to hide it. This would work for what you need to do.

Comment: Is it also valid to do this with existing elements inside the `<head>`? Or are there other consequences when manipulating them with css?

Comment: No, you should not put elements in the `<head>` tag. Put it inside the `<body>` tag.